# How to draw donut chart using canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

please I need your help , my question is If I want to draw donut chart using canvas , how can I do this with canvas and java script,

I wrote the following  code but I do not know how to complete

```
<body>

    <canvas id="chart" width="500" height="500" style="background-color:black">  </canvas>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var canvas  = document.getElementById("chart");
        var chart = canvas.getContext("2d");

        function drawdountChart(canvas)
        {

            this.x , this.y , this.radius , this.lineWidth , this.strockStyle , this.from , this.to = null;
            this.set = function( x, y, radius, from, to, lineWidth, strockStyle)
            {
                this.x = x;
                this.y = y;
                this.radius = radius;
                this.from=from;
                this.to= to;
                this.lineWidth = lineWidth;
                this.strockStyle = strockStyle; 
            }

            this.draw = function(data)
            {
                canvas.beginPath();
                canvas.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
                canvas.strokeStyle = this.strockStyle;
                canvas.arc(this.x , this.y , this.radius , this.from , this.to);
                canvas.stroke();
                var numberOfParts = data.numberOfParts;
                var parts = data.parts.pt;
                var colors = data.colors.cs;
               for(var i = 0; i<numberOfParts; i++)
               {

               }
            }
        }
        var data = 
            {
                numberOfParts: 4,
                parts:{"pt": [20 , 30 , 25 , 25]},//percentage of each part
                colors:{"cs": ["red", "green", "blue", "yellow" ]}//color of each part
            };

        var drawDount = new drawdountChart(chart);
        drawDount.set(150, 150, 100, 0, Math.PI*2, 30, "#FFF");
        drawDount.draw(data);



    </script>


</body>
```

now what I have to put inside the for loop.

Please help me all.

Comment: Hi, there's a tutorial about making interactive pie charts using kineticJS, maybe this can help you get some inspiration http://codefedonarts.com/2013/02/13/interactive-pie-chart-with-kineticjs-tutorial/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You will want to render the parts like this:

```
var df = 0; //keep track of how far round the donut we are.

for(var i = 0; i<numberOfParts; i++) {
  canvas.beginPath();
  canvas.strokeStyle = colors[i]; // get the color
  // Calculate the % of a circle (2PI) to arc
  canvas.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, df, df + (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100)); 
  canvas.stroke();
  // Update our progress around the donut so we know where to draw the next part
  df += (Math.PI * 2) * (parts[i] / 100);
}
```

See it in action here:

http://jsfiddle.net/RgLAU/1/